# Calling to super parent function from child component when it has nested multiple parents

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets assume a React component is having multiple parents. When I wanted to call to a function of the supper parent(The highest level component). How can I do that. Please see the sample code.

```

```
export default class WeekView extends React.Component {      
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    // this functions has to be called from third child
    loadData() {
        var data = [];
        this.setState({events : data});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ChildOne >
        );
    }
}

export class ChildOne extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    } 

    render() {
        return (
            <ChildTwo />
        );
    }
}

export class ChildTwo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    } 

    render() {
        return(
            <ChildThree />
        );
    }
}

export class ChildThree extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    addEvent() {
        // how to call loadData() function, which is included in the highest parent
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Button onCLick={this.addEvent.bind(this)} />
        );
    }
}
```

```

Yeah. we can send the request via the props to the top of the hierarchy. But is there any method we can do it in another way unless going through the hierarchy. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The react way is that you pass functionality from parent components down through props. You mentioned this is your reply.

Basically your parent would have a function which it passes down to a child which then triggers it.

Comment: After learning about this, I got to know That #flux architecture helps to solve this issue.

Comment: Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/yayatucowu/1/embed?js,output) of the concept adopted from [builtwithreact.com](http://buildwithreact.com/tutorial/events)